# Refering highstock.js in requirejs throws error: Cannot read property 'stockChart' of undefined

Tags: highcharts, requirejs, linechart

Hello I am working on creating line charts using Highchart libraries. I need to generate line chart on time intervals like day, week,month, quarter, year etc. So found some examples which uses Highstocks from Highcharts. My project uses requirejs to include scripts. However I have some issues with the js library for highstock. I do not understand if I miss something. My code:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
      jquery: "js/jquery/jquery",
      "datatables.net": "js/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min",
      "datatables.net-css": "js/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.min",
      tippy: "js/tippy.all.min",
      fixedHeader: "js/datatables/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min",
      "fixedHeader-css":"js/datatables/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min",
      jquerymin: "js/jquery-1.10.2.min",
      colpick: "js/colpick",
      colpickcss: "css/colpick",
      highstock: "js/highstock"
    },
    shim: {
      "datatables.net": ["jquery", "css!datatables.net-css"],
      fixedHeader: ["css!fixedHeader-css"],
      colpick: ["css!colpickcss"]
    }
  });
    require.config({
        priority: ["jquery", "jquerymin", "colpick"]
    });
  require([
    "jquery", "tippy",  "DS/3DXHighcharts/3DXHighcharts", "highstock", "datatables.net", "fixedHeader", "jquerymin", "colpick"], 
    function(
    $, tippy, Highcharts, highstock  )
```

When i try to generate the chart:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container',chartData);
```

I get error : Cannot read property 'stockChart' of undefined.

I am trying to do something like below :
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/smbc6gr4/

Comment: Hi @sina123, Please check this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8890 and docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts#load-highcharts-from-the-cdn-as-an-amd-module If you have any further questions - just ask.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek I have tried that but have issues when referring the highstock file that is in the server. It works fine when it is a URL but not otherwise and I am not sure what should be changed in the code so as to make it work. I always get undefined .

Comment: Please continue the discussion in the github thread.